# Creating symbolic links from an Android java app

Tags: android

I'm developing a small android java app - i'm a real newbie with android.
I'm looking for a way to create a symbolic link from my application on a certain directory.

I need to execute this as root - this assume the owner of the phone has root permissions on his file system.

Can someone pls help me?
I couldn't find it... if there isn't an API for this is there an alternative, like running a native script or something?

Thanx!
Gili

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: No API? I also need to copy files from one place to another, something like cp -r -p ... Everything should be done with the runtime?

Comment: Why would there be an API for doing what can only be done by root? Android apps aren't really meant to use the linux filesystem or linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't really get the vm's process escalated to root, you are going to have to launch another process using whatever root obtaining mechanism ("su" etc) the custom rom supports.  That process should be either a stand alone native executable (made by (ab)using the ndk's gcc) or a shell script.

Obviously none of this is supported in the official android builds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't ever need root in my app!

All I want is to create symbolic links from the internal storage dir reserved for my app `(Context.getFilesDir())` to real files on /sdcard.

It's curious, but I see no way to do that without JNI...